# Where should I place public static void Main?

Tags: c#

I am currently reading the Microsoft Official Course books for C# programming, the first concept they introduce you to is `Console.WriteLine`

The actual code they give you to type is:

```
class Hello
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether I am supposed to place this code under Form Load or using System because I always get the following error(s) and I am not sure what it implies:

> Error  ...Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'Hello.Main()'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.**

Comment: It looks like you create a winforms project by mistake instead of a console one.

Comment: Your project actually had two static methods named `Main`. One of these two was generated by the integrated development environment Visual Studio, and the other one was hand-written by you. When there are two `Main` (each static and with a valid signature for "entry points"), the compiler can't tell which one to use, and you get the error.

Comment: Please note that `Main` [should *not* be public](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is code for a `console` application, not a `WinForm` application. In Visual Studio, create a new project and select `Console Application` as the project type.

You'll notice that a new console project will have most of the code you've got written for you (e.g. the `Main` method)

[image]

The reason you were getting that error was because WinForm already has a `Main` method in `Program.cs`. The Main method is known as the [entry point](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479467/Main-Method-in-Csharp) and .net standalone exe projects have one. You can make the entry point another method but this is rarely done as there's no real need to in the majority of cases.

Comment: Just for the record, a Windows Forms application has a Main method as well. It's just that the default template already adds it for you, and most people never touch the file that contains it again.

Comment: Mentioned that as you were typing that comment :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Edited that to point out standalone projects.

Comment: Notice it's `static void Main(string[] args)`. This means `args` is a [string array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Also, C# is case-sensitive so you need to make sure it's lowercase `static void`. If you run it by pressing F5 (which runs in Debug mode), you'll see a black window flash. This is because the program has executed and completed so the console window (the black window) closes. To fix this, add `Console.ReadLine();` after `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World");`. This tells the program to wait for the user to press return before closing.

Comment: Alternatively, you can launch your program by pressing CTRL + F5. This doesn't run in debug mode but for console applications, the console window will automatically remain open without the `Console.ReadLine();` statement. (Both, the F5 and CTRL + F5, run options can be found in the `DEBUG` menu at the top). Your output should be visible within this console window.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong application type.

The course probably mentions somewhere that you should create a new `Console Application`.  You have chosen `Windows Forms` in your attempt.

Try creating a new `Console Application`, and the `Main` method will already be defined for you.